# pandas.DataFrame.apply() with a parameter?

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I've got a portfolio DataFrame with a list of stocks and quantities:

```
stock, quantity
AAPL, 100
GOOG, 50
```

I've got a function `lookup(stock, date)` which returns the price.

What's the most elegant way to apply `lookup()` to the stock `DataFrame`?

PS I would use `DataFrame.apply()` but I don't believe I can supply the date.

Comment: So where should the date come from?

Comment: look at `args` argument: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def lookup(stock, date):
    prices = {('AAPL', '2016-01-01'): 1, ('GOOG', '2016-01-01'): 2}
    return prices[(stock, date)]

>>> date = '2016-01-01'
>>> df.apply(lambda x: lookup(x[0], date), axis=1)
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64
```

If `stock` is the index, use:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: lookup(x.name, date), axis=1)
```

Comment: That pretty cool actually, I learnt something too! Thanks! I have one question, x[0] is bringing up the quantity (I think 'AAPL' is in the index in my case)- how can I grab the stock instead?

Comment: Try: `df.apply(lambda x: lookup(x.name, date), axis=1)`